# How do i delete a group of files ending with specific characters?

Tags: macos, command-line, file

I'm trying to delete files that end with "_n.png" or "_s.png". How do i do that?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are many *files* that meet the *specifications* and may be in more then one location, I'd use the `find` *command* from **Terminal**, as shown in the following simple example:

```
$ find . -type f \( -iname '*_n.png' -o -iname '*_s.png' \)
./Pictures/foobar_n.png
./Pictures/Temp/barfoo_s.png
$
```

In the *output* of the `find` *command* above, we see it found the two sample files I created for testing. As I'm sure those are the files I want to delete I run the same *command* but with adding `-delete` to it, as shown below:

```
find . -type f \( -iname '*_n.png' -o -iname '*_s.png' \) -delete
```

If all the *files* are in the same *directory* or you just want to delete these *files* in a specific *directory*, use:

```
cd /path/to/directory
rm *_[ns].png
```

**NOTE: Using `find` with the `-delete` *option* or `rm` immediately deletes the files found, they are not placed in the Trash and they are generally not recoverable!**

**So do not use this commands unless you're okay with the note above!**

---

If you prefer to use a **GUI** method, there is a nice freeware app by **DEVONtechnologies, LLC** called **EasyFind** and is available in the **App Store** or the developers website.

- [EasyFind - Mac App Store Preview](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12)
- [EasyFind - Developers Website](https://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html)

As you can see in the image below, **EasyFind** found the sample *files* created for testing. Simply select the ones you want to delete and then click **Delete** on its **Toolbar** to place the selected items in the **Trash**.

[image: EasyFind Search Results]

The nice feature of **EasyFind** is , with its various setting and controls, it's capable of making some searches that are not possible to perform in **Finder** while providing the user with a **GUI** interface, and without having to use **Terminal**.

<sup>Note that I'm not affiliated with the developer of EasyFind, just a happy user of the product.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the folder containing the files in Finder
2. Press Command-F
3. Change the first pulldown to "Name"
4. Change the second pulldown to "ends with"
5. Enter your search criteria, e.g. "_s.png"
6. Drag the files from the search result to the Trash

[image: Finder search name ends with]

Option-clicking the "+" icon (at the end of the filter row) changes the icon to "…" which allows you to combine search operations, e.g. find files ending with both search terms in one search operation.

[image: Finder search combine terms]